# День недели и месяц с заглавной в SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Для вывода даты используя формат в таком виде:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM", Locale.getDefault());
String title = formatter.format(new Date());
mDateTitle.setText(title);
```

И при английской локализации телефона работает корректно, то есть `Wednesday, 07 March`. А когда русский, то с маленькой, то есть `среда, 07 марта`.

Так вот, в чем может быть проблема? Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 6):

Я не спец по ГОСТ-ам, но похоже что так и надо, как пруфлинк:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSS28S_8.1.0/XFDL/i_xfdl_r_formats_ru_RU.html

> full | EEEE, d MMMM yyyy 'г'. | пятница, 13 июня 2003 г.

Если вам все-таки критично что день недели и месяц с маленькой, "капитализируйте" строку.
В Kotlin функция идет из коробки
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html

Для Java придется погуглить библиотеку или написать самому.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать переопределить дни недели:

```
DateFormatSymbols myDateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols() {
    @Override
    public String[] getWeekdays() {
        return new String[] {"", "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"};
    }
};

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", myDateFormatSymbols);
```